# Can't import WMI Python module

Tags: python, python-3.x, wmi

I'm new to python.
I'm working in windows environment. mostly win7.
My machine is win7 32bit also.
I downloaded the wmi module and used the .exe to install it.
when I try and 'import wmi', i get an error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
        import wmi
      File "C:\Python33\lib\wmi.py", line 88, in <module>
        from win32com.client import GetObject, Dispatch
    ImportError: No module named 'win32com'
```

How can I solve this? Does win7 compliant with this module?

Regards

Answer (score 4):

download WMI-1.4.9.win32.exe from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/WMI/ and it will resolve your problem

Answer (score 4):

Instead you can also install win32com which would resolve the issue.
To install win32com use:

pip install pypiwin32

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is:
i downloaded the source named: `WMI-1.4.9.zip` from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/WMI/
Extracted all files from that zip file and saved it in a folder named: `WMI-1.4.9` and then copied that folder to C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages.
After that I navigated to that folder C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\WMI-1.4.9 and did a shift + right click -> Open Command line here and ran: `python setup.py install`

That's it, after that it worked for me like charm. No issues.

p.s - While installing exe I had some weird Access Denied errors, I tried by running the exe as Administrator even then I could get through it. Hence that didn't at all work for me.

Also I had pywin32 installed from here:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/ (select the correct file - 'bittedness' and python version wise)