# Pywin32 FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ...\\__init__.py

Tags: python, wmi, pywin32

I am trying to use [WMI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/WMI/). It's required that I install pywin32 which I did. But when I import WMI, it returns an error. Can anyone help me!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\wmi.py", line 88, in <module>
    from win32com.client import GetObject, Dispatch
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from . import gencache
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\gencache.py", line 666, in <module>
    __init__()
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\gencache.py", line 62, in __init__
    Rebuild()
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\gencache.py", line 653, in Rebuild
    _SaveDicts()
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\gencache.py", line 69, in _SaveDicts
    f = open(os.path.join(GetGeneratePath(), "dicts.dat"), "wb")
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\gencache.py", line 145, in GetGeneratePath
    f = open(fname,"w")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\KEVINE~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\gen_py\\3.6\\__init__.py'
```

Comment: Welcome on SO! Do you run your code as member of the Administrator group?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't import WMI Python module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20654047/cant-import-wmi-python-module)

Answer (score 0):

I tried this myself and can confirm wmi works in Anaconda running Python 2.7.

What I did:

1. Started the Anaconda Prompt (python2)
2. conda install pywmi32 (pywin32: 220-py27_1 was already install, nothing to do).
3. `pip install wmi`
4. Run the following test sample in Spyder, or on the prompt `python wmi_test.py`

```python
import wmi    
c = wmi.WMI ()
for s in c.Win32_Service (StartMode="Auto", State="Stopped"):
  if raw_input ("Restart %s? " % s.Caption).upper () == "Y":
    s.StartService ()
```

As a baseline test you can even run the WMI module directly and get some information about your disks:

```
python C:\Users\itsyou\Anaconda3\envs\python2\Lib\site-packages\wmi.py
```

Comment: By the way, in my book PowerShell is the weapon of choice to deal with WMI.

Comment: PowerShell is definitely the tool to be used to access WMI on Windows. Don't miss CIM and WMI cmdlets.